PDF of $R=\frac{\Vert\mathbf{x}\mathbf{A}\Vert^2}{\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert^2}$ for a given matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and with $\mathbf{x}$ Gaussian random
Given a matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ symmetric positive definite, I'm interested in the distribution of the random variable
$$R=\frac{\Vert\mathbf{x}\mathbf{A}\Vert^2}{\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert^2},$$
where $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{C}^{1\times N}$ is a random vector whose entries are i.i.d. complex Guassian distributed with zero mean and unit variance, i.e., $\mathbf{x}\sim\mathcal{CN}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{I})$, and $\Vert\cdot\Vert^2$ denotes the Euclidean norm.
I could only find the following information on $R$:

$R$ solely depends on the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$, and an alternative representation is given by
$$R=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N\lambda_n^2\vert x_n\vert^2}{\sum_{n=1}^N\vert x_n\vert^2},$$
where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_N$ are the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ are the entries of $\mathbf{x}$.
$R$ is lower bounded by the smallest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$ squared and upper bounded by the largest eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$ squared.
A good approximation for the mean of $R$ seems to be
$$\text{E}\left[R\right]\approx\frac{\text{E}\left[\Vert\mathbf{x}\mathbf{A}\Vert^2\right]}{\text{E}\left[\Vert\mathbf{x}\Vert^2\right]}=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N\lambda_n^2}{N}=\frac{\text{Trace}\left(\mathbf{A}^2\right)}{N}.$$

Any help would be much appreciated, even for the random variable $\sqrt{R}$ and/or in the limit $N\rightarrow\infty$.
